# Extracting utilities into libraries for python microservice applications

Tags: python, structure, microservices

TL;DR: Any advice or resources on extracting code to reusable, well-structured and maintainable libraries?

I'm working on python applications in a microservice-style architecture, where we'll be developing and deploying a bunch of small applications, each solving a specific issues, maybe (or maybe not) by interacting with other applications/external services.

We just started moving to that microservice architecture, so we already have quite a bit of code in a monolithic project. As we're adding new microservices, it's obvious that we need to extract common code(e.g. utilities, base classes, ...) into libraries to avoid reimplementing or copy-pasting code that will then have to be maintained separately. As I'm trying to do that(which I've never really done before), I'm realizing it's not trivial and can become complicated pretty quickly, and I could spend some time overthinking it too.

So I'm looking for advices, or pointers to resources on best-practices related to this situation, i.e. writing well-structured python libraries, packaging and distributing libraries, sharing code in a microservice architecture and avoiding making mistakes that might put me in problematic situations, .

Concrete problems/challenges I'm facing:
* How best to group/separate code in version control. Like, one repository per package? The number of repositories can explode pretty quickly...

Comment: A lot of times, especially when developing a business application, microservices has no meaning from a technical standpoint. The real question to ask first before deciding the technical problems are the business domain and how you intend to split it out. If you can include some examples as what you're trying to do, people will be more likely and able to help.

Comment: The microservice part is not that important, I mentioned it for context, and with microservice architecture becoming pretty common and popular, and with all big companies using that architecture, I would expect this problematic would already have been encountered, discussed and addressed. This is not a code issue, this is about project architecture and dependency management. I realize my question is maybe a bit too abstract/unclear for stackoverflow.

Comment: Right, but how you're going to split it out will determine whats reusable as a library, package, etc depends on the domain while infrastructure doesn't depend too much on that.

Comment: Right, true. I guess I was looking for case studies, "Here's how we've done it" type stories/articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For shared libraries you can publish it to git in individual repositories and set them up to use Python package managers to install them in your project.

As far as application deployments, service dependencies, etc. I would advise for you to take a look at Docker for containerization, docker-compose for service dependencies locally, Artifactory or ECR for Docker image registries, and container orchestration platforms like Kubernetes.

Containers are similar to the virtual machines but at a more granular level, the process level. This effectively will allow you to run services together locally for testing and deploying them. It would no longer matter that each service is in a different repository.

If you don't have too many microservices, you could definitely use a mono-repo but if your engineering organization is large, its pretty costly to download all the updates for all the services. As an alternative, you may have your services that are divided in respective bounded contexts all live in a single repo to remove this deterrent. Long story short, it really depends what you will find beneficial. At the end of the day, the largest problems are never how many Git repositories you have, its how you define the bounds of your services, the service-to-service communication and infrastructure for deploying the services.

Comment: Is this not the answer you were looking for? If not, can you be more specific about the question you're asking. If the only concern is number of repositories, I think this will cover all grounds. Whats your primary concern here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant to force the answer on you. I just wanted to see where I may be able to clarify to better answer your question :). Let me know if there's any other things I can address here related to that question.

Comment: No, that's all right. I guess you did answer my question in your last paragraph.